# Windows names a bounced wifi router with a '2' suffix, no outgoing connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

We have two Windows 7 laptops that connect through an older Belkin ADSL modem / wifi router. We have a second Siemens wifi router on the network that acts as an extender.

Frequently, when the router happens to restart (typically because a child-initiated-power-cycle) the wireless network will reappear, but with a '2' appended to the ssid.

After that we don't seem to be able to get a connection to the outside world, either after disconnecting and reconnecting or powercycling the router again. Only a laptop reboot seems to fix things.

I can't seem to hit on the right question to ask the internet, so any suggestions gratefully received even if not the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar, though not identical issue, which was caused by having a router/modem and a wireless bridge on different channels. This happened when I changed the channel on the router due to interference and clean forgot about the bridge :-)

If the two were started in the correct order, everything was fine - but if not, Windows 7 machines that picked the bridge up as the stronger wireless signal exhibited symptoms like those you describe. Strangely, an XBox that was wired into the bridge and iDevices were fine.

Might not be the issue, but worth checking(?)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I may have your point about-face -- my two devices are ethernet-connected, so I'd assume I need different channels.